# react adds only one item in to array instead of keep on adding?

Tags: reactjs

I have this code
what I want to happen is once I click on the div with class flexrow (see code) an icon should show up, once that happen I want to use the icon to add more items to the movement ul(see code), the way it is working correctly is when I place the icon already on the UI then I have no issues it works fine but I want the icon to be shown on demand and there where the issue is it creates only one element and stops any idea what I am doing wrong thanks.

```js
function StabelBoxUtility() {

    let item = [<StabelItem />]
    const [icons, setIcon] = useState([]);
    const [stabelItem, setStabelItem] = useState({items:[]});
    const addStabelItem = () => {
        setStabelItem({items:[...stabelItem.items, item]})
    }
    const showIcon = ()=> {
      setIcon(<FontAwesomeIcon className="changable margin-left" onClick={() => {addStabelItem()}} icon={["fas", "plus-circle"]} size="lg" />)
      console.log('yes');
    }
    return (
        <ul className="utility">
    <li className="box-item" >
        <div className="flexrow" onClick={()=>{showIcon()}}>
            <div className='number norest'>total</div>
            <div className='number calc margin-left norest'>0</div>
        </div>
        <ul className="movements">
        {stabelItem.items}
        {icons}
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
    )
}

export default StabelBoxUtility
```

Comment: `item` is, confusingly (it me, anyway) an array of `StabelItem` components. `stabelItem` therefore, is an object with an `items` property which is an array of an array of `StabelItem` components. I'm not sure how React's change detection algorithm is going to handle that. Seems like it would be more intuitive to have `item` be a single `StabelItem` component, and to have `items` hold an array of those components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the item variable is also an array you should also spread the variable like this

```
const addStabelItem = () => {
        setStabelItem({items:[...stabelItem.items, ...item]})
    }
```

Also I would suggest you to rewrite all the on clicks function like this. Because this is professional. As you are not passing any parameters.

```
onClick={showIcon}
```

Comment: I tried to spread but still not adding more than one

Comment: I think you posted another comment? About the function?

Comment: my bad it was a mistake, although the item is still getting created only once unless the icon is fixed and not shown on demand

Comment: Do you mean that still it is not adding new component in the state. Did you console log the state that is it added or not?